# How to get the value by GET method from URL Parameter?

Tags: url, get, arguments

I have a problem with this script:

```html
<form action="edit.php" method="GET">
<a class="btn btn-default" href="editj.php?id=3">Edit</a>
</form>
```

in my edit.php file i have:

```html
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"xml:lang="pl" lang="pl">
<head> 
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="content-langiage" content="pl" />
 <title>Praca inżynierska</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
 <div id="kontener_glowny">
    <?php
      include 'topmenu.php';
    ?>
  <div id="kontener">

          <?php

           $id = $_GET['$id'];
           echo $id;
           ?>


  
  </div>
  <div id="stopka">
     Stopka
  </div>
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

and my web browser show me error: Notice: Undefined index: $id in M:\xampp\htdocs\apka\edit.php on line 19.

I have no idea how can i get value of my argument which i have in link,
this script should show me id=3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use **$_GET['id']** instead of **$_GET['$id']**

Comment: Thank you a lot.
I have an extra question.
Why when I add a form tags and try to use in the same file (edit.php)
method POST, i have the same error.

Comment: In that case, you've to use **$_POST['id']** instead of $_GET['id']